# How can use Struts 2.0, Spring and Hibernate in my framework

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, struts2

Is it possible put these three framework Spring, Struts 2.0 and Hibernate in single application and how without using JPA?

Comment: Put yourself in our position, and re-read your question. Do you think it's answerable?

Comment: Put these frameworks in where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2, Spring and Hibernate ARE frameworks, so your question makes little sense. If you mean "can I use Struts2, Spring and Hibernate to build my web application?", the answer is yes, in principle - they play together all right.

Comment: yes you are correct. I have rephrase the question for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Check the official documentation of springsource to know how it works and how to implement them.

[Spring Official documentation](http://www.springsource.org/documentation)
Look at Current Releases -> Reference manual, of your version. Everything is explained.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provide, use the Hibernate JPA implementation and you are done.